# How to make some filters mandatory in tastypie?

Tags: python, django, rest, filtering, tastypie

```
class LinguistResource(ModelResource):

    class Meta:
        model = Linguist
        queryset = Linguist.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'linguists_by_language'
        filtering = {
            "language": ('exact', ),
        }
```

Is it possible to make "language" filter mandatory?

My goal is raise error if in GET parameters absent key "language"

Answer (score 13):

You can catch this by overriding [build_filters](http://readthedocs.org/docs/django-tastypie/en/v0.9.10/resources.html#build-filters):

```
from tastypie.exceptions import BadRequest

def build_filters(self, filters=None):
    if 'language' not in filters:
         raise BadRequest("missing language param") # or maybe create your own exception
    return super(LinguistResource, self).build_filters(filters)
```